# Javascript array in function

Tags: javascript, arrays

My little problem is that when I call function go. I want when logic = true return array and when logic = false, so I need delete all elements in this array, but this solution doesn´t work.

```
function go(logic) {

if (logic) 
{
    return array;
    array = [];
}
else
{
    array = [];
}

$("#ok").click(function(){array.push(1);});
$("#close").click(function(){array.push(2);});

var array = [];

}
```

Comment: Is array stored outside of the go function? What isn't working?

Comment: when `logic = false`, you empty the array but then you push `1` into it...?

Comment: #making When I stored outside, so when I call function, so when return me array, so I alert this array and array is as many times as the call.
#Vic I have elese code instead array.push(1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code after the return won't be executed.

Guess you're using a global var? But I don't understand why you set the array var at the end of the function...

```
function go(logic) {
  if (logic) {
    var tmp = array;
    array = [];
    return tmp;
  } else {
    array = [];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you want this instead:

```
function go(array, logic){
    return logic ? array : [];
}
```

This uses the [conditional operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/?%3a#JavaScript). The function will return the original array if your condition is satisfied, otherwise, it returns an empty array.

You can then use it to reset an array like this:

```
array = go(array, logic);
```

Comment: No, this is not what I meant. I call this function many times and I need, when I call go with true, so go return me this array, with elements, which I put. Otherwise array was null. Do you understand what I want? :)

Comment: 1) Does the array start having any elements before the `go` call? 2) What elements need to be added if(logic)?

Comment: 1) Yes, because when I call go first time(array = null), so after I click on ok or close. But this time with false. After them I call with true, so I need return array with element and after them array don´t have a elemets.
2) No, for example this:
$("#ok").click(function(){array.push(1);});

Answer (score 0):

If i got this right you need to do it like this:

```
function go(logic){

   //if logic is false clear array
   if(!logic){
      x = [];
   } 
   //return the array
   //now empty if !logic
   return x;
}
//create array
var x = [];
//push values on click
$('.elem').click(function(){x.push('someval');});
```